# When using ARC, is there a difference between [[NSArray alloc] init] and the "autorelased" [NSArray array]?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C: With ARC, what's better? alloc or autorelease initializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776537/objective-c-with-arc-whats-better-alloc-or-autorelease-initializers)

Does ARC automatically turn the autoreleased versions of class initializers into the appropriate non-autorelased versions, or are they still technically being autoreleased?

I don't want to keep memory around any longer than it's absolutely required, so I've gotten in the habit of using alloc/init in almost all circumstances.  Now in ARC, I'm wondering if I can just start using the "autorelease" initializers and expect them to act like a non-autorelased versions would behave...

Does anyone have any documentation on where I can find out what happens to autoreleased methods under ARC?

Comment: The answers to this question - essentially the same - suggests that the autorelease versions are actually faster: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776537/objective-c-with-arc-whats-better-alloc-or-autorelease-initializers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get an autoreleased object, ARC will manage to avoid the autorelease pool, **as long as both your code and the called method/function are compiled with ARC**.

ARC adds a call to `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue` in your code and a call to `objc_autoreleaseReturnValue` in the called function/method. At runtime when `objc_autoreleaseReturnValue` sees that the returned value will be retained by `objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue`, it doesn't autorelease the object and sets a flag to tell `objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue` not to retain the object. Thus you get no (perceptible) extra cost for using a convenient creation method rather that `alloc`/`init`.

For more information about that mechanism, you may read [How does objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue work?](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/2012/02/how-does-objc_retainautoreleasedreturnvalue-work/) by Matt Galloway.

In conclusion, just use the method you prefer, Apple engineers will ensure it runs fast.

Comment: Thanks, this explains it perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Well technically they're not the same, since ARC simply inserts 'retains' and 'releases' into your code (where necessary) when it's compiled.

Answer (score 0):

ARC stores a strong reference to an object if you use a pointer when initiating it, otherwise it deallocs the object immediately. So I believe the answer to your question about NSArray is that no, ARC does not turn it into an autoreleased object. It also adds a release statement to the code whenever the object is no longer needed in a scope:

```
-(void) aMethod
{
    [NSArray alloc];
}

//in essence is transformed into

-(void) aMethod
{
    NSArray *temp = [NSArray alloc];
    [temp release];
}
```

If you had stored a pointer, ARC would add a release as soon as the object was about to leave the scope.