# Should I prefer factory (convenience) constructors over allocation and initialisation?

Tags: objective-c, foundation

A lot of Foundation objects provide two interfaces for creation:

1. The general `NSObject` `init` method:

   `_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`
2. A specialised factory method (convenience constructor), such as:

   `_array = [NSMutableArray array];`

I've recently developed a habit of doing the latter, and I was wondering if there was a reason to prefer one over the other.

I use ARC, so the autorelease nature of convenience constructors isn't a consideration per se.

Comment: If you use `ARC` then this answer pretty much covers you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776537/objective-c-with-arc-whats-better-alloc-or-autorelease-initializers

Comment: @Girish - I'll edit the question to reflect that I'm only interested in the differences under ARC

Comment: Those methods are called convenience constructors in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Convenience constructors are a little easier to use. They have the possible downside of an additional autorelease. ARC might optimize that away, though.