# Objective C: Initialization of Objects

Tags: objective-c

If I wanted to create a UIImage for example, what would be the difference in the following two lines of code:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];
```

Is it just a case of "same end, different means"?

Answer (score 5):

`imageWithCGImage:` returns an autoreleased instance while `initWithCGImage:` returns an image that you must release yourself.  Typically you can count on a class method to return an autoreleased object while any instance `init` method returns an object you must release.

If you are using ARC code, they basically do the same thing, but see this related question for more information: [With ARC, what's better: alloc or autorelease initializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776537/objective-c-with-arc-whats-better-alloc-or-autorelease-initializers)

Comment: @ConnorLirot you still need to have a pretty good understanding of how memory management works under ARC. So, yes, it does apply.

Comment: Under ARC, the choice of which to use generally doesn't matter. The only time you probably need to care with ARC is when working around an `@autoreleasepool`.

Comment: @rmaddy Could you expand on what could happen when working around an @autoreleasepool?

Comment: @ConnorLirot this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086913/objective-c-why-is-autorelease-autoreleasepool-still-needed-with-arc

Comment: @ConnorLirot There was a question a day or two ago that ran into this issue but I can't find it now. It had to do with assigning an autoreleased object inside an `@autorelease` block to a variable declared before the block. The solution was to use `alloc/init` instead of the autoreleased version.